# TypeLoadException using Ninject MVC3: NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin doesn't implement GetRequestScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have spent hours on trying to figure out why, after upgrading Ninject and Ninject.Web.Common to the latest versions, I have been getting this TypeLoadException.

I have the answer, which I will post, in case others get the same thing.

Comment: If you're trying to make something like this searchable, it helps to put in the *actual* exception

Comment: Is it this exception? `"Method 'GetRequestScope' in type 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin' from assembly 'Ninject.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' does not have an implementation.":"Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin"`

Comment: Can't remember, but it doesn't happen with the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin has changed at some point from using RequestScope as a property to GetRequestScope as a method.

Ninject.MVC3 has not been updated, so it is a breaking change.

To fix the problem, either don't upgrade yet, or install the pre-release 3.0.2 version of Ninject.MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

You're more than likely mixing Stable and Unstable NuGet packages. If you use all one or all the other, you're fine. If you're not, you're not.

Comment: Using all stable versions causes the problem I have described. I had to use an unstable version of Ninject.MVC3 in order to get it to work, i.e. it looks like whoever made the last ninject released messed up.